# TCP Socket communication Java - Python

Tags: java, python, sockets, servlets

I want to transmit an integer number throught a socket.
I have a python script that open a socket and wait for requests, in the other side there is a Java servlet that send a request at this socket to obtain a value.

All the communication works well the problem is that the value obtained from java cause a EOFexception. I've tried some convertion and formats in the python script (I'm not expert of this language) but nothing works.

Instead, if I use in python a echo socket, picking all that socket receive and send back to java, all working fine.

But I need to send a simple value.

The following is the portion of code that I use, I've tried with float, this is with a String value:

[Python socket related istructions]

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
connection = sock.accept()
```

[Python echo socket working]

```
data = connection.recv(16)
if data:
    connection.sendall(data)
```

instead I want to do:

[Python return a example value]

```
 connection.sendall('55')
```

That working if I send request from a client like [Hercules](https://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) but cause a EOFexception in Java

[Java Servlet - send request]

```
socket = new Socket(address, port);
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String content = dataInputStream.readUTF(); //EOFexception
Destination.value = content;
```

Comment: `DataInputStream` is only for use when the other end of the connection is using `DataOutputStream`.  The Python side is not sending anything that `DataInputStream` understands.  You should be using a regular `InputStream`.  After you get that fixed you'll find another issue in that you're sending a _string_ value from Python, not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using InputStream instead of DataInputStream, write the python socket to send string as byte and changed the java receiver to read byte stream and convert in to string (good format for my purpose).